# Is it possible to determine a method's callback if its type is void and its "return;" had skipped its execution?

Tags: junit, callback, void, java-6

I have a method which works like this:

```
public void deploy(UserInput userInput)  {
   if (userInput is wrong)
      return;

   //start deployment process
}
```

The userInput consist of individual checks in the deploy method. Now, I'd like to JUnit test if the user input check algorithms behave right (so if the deployment process would start or not depending on the right or wrong user input). So I need to test this with right and wrong user inputs. I could do this task by checking if anything has been deployed at all, but in this case this is very cumbersome. 
So I wonder if it's somehow possible to know in the corresponding JUnit test if the deploy method has been aborted or not (due to wrong user inputs)? (By the way, changing the deploy method is no option.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a UserInput stub / mock with the correct expectations and verify that only the expected calls (and no more) were made.

However, from a design point of view, if you were able to split your validation and the deployment process into separate classes - then your code can be as simple as:

```
if (_validator.isValid(userInput)) {
  _deployer.deploy(userInput);
}
```

This way you can easily test that if the validator returns false the deployer is never called (using a mocking framework, such as jMock) and that it is called if the validator returns true.

It will also enable you to test your validation and deployment code seperately, avoiding the issue you're currently having.

Comment: A separate class with the algorithm would a possible solution, but I'm not sure if this is a little bit over-engineered. To the first sentence. How can I check if the expected calls (e.g. right if/else branches in an algorithm) were made? I don't think that this is possible, not even with reflections.

Comment: It's in keeping with SOLID principals. Also, since the current design has caused you to ask a question on SO, changing it to be more amenable to testing seems reasonable.

Comment: You will need to inject your dependencies, which in your tests take the form of instances that are entirely controlled by you, you can make assertions about many things this way. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-mocktest/index.html for an introduction on using mocks in tests.

Comment: Ok, I'm persuaded. It's no good design when some parts (of a method) are not testable. I will redesign that.

Answer (score 2):

As you describe your problem, you can only check your method for side effects, or if it throws an Exception. The easiest way to do this is using a mocking framework like JMockit or Mockito. You have to mock the first method after the checking of user input has finished:

```
public void deploy(UserInput userInput)  {
   if (userInput is wrong)
      return;

   //start deployment process
   startDeploy(); // mock this method
}
```

You can also extend the class under test, and override startDeploy() if it's possible. This would avoid having to use a mocking framework.

### Alternative - Integration tests

It sounds like the deploy method is large and complex, and deals with files, file systems, external services (ftp), etc.

It is sometimes easier in the long run to just accept that you're dealing with external systems, and test these external systems. For instance, if deploy() copies a file to directory x, test that the file exists in the target directory. I don't know how complex deploy is, but often mocking these methods can be as hard as just testing the actual behaviour. This may be cumbersome, but like most tests, it would allow you refactor your code so it is simpler to understand. If your goal is refactoring, then in my experience, it's easier to refactor if you're testing actual behaviour rather than mocking.

Comment: Thanks, we are already thought about using Mockito too. But this time it's better to put the algorithm into another method, because it rightly doesn't belong to "deploy". So now I can test the algorithm by itself. By the way, this deploy method itself is very small because we only delegate it here to the current target which can be a database or a file system. I don't even have a "startDeploy" method or similar. So I think this would make it much more diffcult to use mock objects in this case.